# change left-hand boolean value to be opposite of the right hand value

Tags: c#

I am not sure this is even possible but let's say you want to show either label A or label B based on a condition and hide the other, **in the same line**.  So if label A is visible, label B is hidden and vice-versa.  If I wanted to set both label A and B visible, I could simply do

```
lableA.Visible = LabelB.Visible = true
```

However, what if I only wanted label A visible? Is that possible? Something like

```
labelA.Visible = labelB.Visible not = true
```

This may not even be doable without an auxiliary method or override or something; I'm just wondering if anyone out there has found anything like it.

Comment: This is an *excellent* use case for bindings if you are using WPF.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET, also I was just wondering if it's doable in one line.  It's completely trivial doing it in case binding or if / else statement, etc.

Comment: You would simply do labelA.Visible = true; labelB.Visible = false;.  You gain nothing by trying to collapse that into a single line.

Comment: Is doing it in 2 lines too slow? In that case, upgrade your computer.

Comment: It's possible to write an entire method in one line too. I am trying to avoid the unorthodox practices however.

Comment: Zohad, please look up "ad hominem".  My goal is to see if there is a quick-hand expression that I can write, not see if I can run a code under a 486/66 processor.

Comment: Aren't you just saying `LabelA.Visible = True; LabelB.Visible = !(LabelA.Visible);`?

Comment: AIG, yes, without the semi-colon if possible. Again, this is just to pique my curiosity, not to achieve anything.  My goal was to write some code for a lot of such labels.  Not enough to implement recursion but enough to where it would look ugly with many lines, so I thought this may be a way to go.

Comment: You could do what M.KazemAkhgary has suggested below, but that is, IMO, the unorthodox thing to do.  Putting the assignments in two separate statements, even if you put them in the same line, is more readable/"orthodox".

Comment: No matter how "clever" doing this with a single line is, you're losing clarity and introducing potential for buggy implementation by not splitting this out into several (two) lines.

Comment: *"I am trying to avoid the unorthodox practices however*" If you want to avoid "unorthodox" practices, don't try to be uniquely clever. If you really, really have to think and crowd-source a unique solution, its probably not the right thing to do when there is a much easier way (two lines).

Comment: Thank you everyone.  I will abstain from doing the one-line solution and choose clarity over cleverness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd send code back to the author if they did something like this

```
a = !(b = true);
```

For the sanity of anyone who has to deal with your code, stick to an operation per line.

```
b = true;
a = !b;
```

The former requires a double-take and a few seconds of brain-time to understand. The latter is perfectly clear.

If you feel differently, then you wouldn't have had to ask in the first place... It would be obvious, no?

Comment: On the contrary, I'll give you an up vote AND I will follow your example.  The question has been answered, so Mkazem gets a check mark, but I would be an idiot to ignore such an overwhelming voice of disapproval for the practice.  So, thank you.

Comment: And I am happy to disappoint you by giving you an upvote instead :-)

Comment: @Lukas feel free to accept this. ;) people change their mind overtime and thats normal. But i just wanted to give straight answer. And here is my +1

Comment: Much respected M.Kazem. Thank you!  Now if someone would kindly take back their anonymous -1 from my post in light of choosing correct practice over correct answer, that would be just lovely.

Answer (score 4):

You can use parenthesis

```
labelA.Visible = !(labelB.Visible = false);
```

This is assignment to both variables. if you want to make one opposite of another just do.

```
labelA.Visible = !labelB.Visible;
```

Comment: Yes, that would do it, but it feels like trying to be too clever IMO. Two statements will be immediately clear to everyone. This will probably make a lot of readers go "huh?"

Comment: Brilliant!  Exactly what I wanted (never mind the readers that go "huh").  Thank you!  Up-vote and check.

Comment: Hmm, need to wait a few minutes before giving you the check :)

Comment: @BrianRasmussen what? lol. i dont know. you can say what ever you want ;)

Comment: I totally agree with @BrianRasmussen. May I never maintain code written with the kind of thinking that puts cleverness above readability when it provides no other benefit.

Comment: Thanks :) Your answer is correct and what the OP wants, but I would value readability over this kind of cleverness. That's all.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen - agree again, and when hiring programmers, if a prospect employee gave me something with a statement like this, they'd lose points on it.

Comment: check added, but in light of the uproar this question has caused, I'll either rewrite the code using multiple lines and conditional statements, or make a clear remark comment explaining to what I am doing to where a 10 year old could immediately see what's going on without much guess work.

Comment: I really don't see anything wrong with this, particularly the second statement. The first is a bit ugly, but the second is completely fine IMO. Especially if you just add a comment like `//toggle label based on other label's visibility`. And obviously the controls will be labeled with actual names, making it even more apparent what's happening.